# Mongodump from remote server

Tags: mongodb, database-dump

We recently ported some data over to MongoDB and are now looking into running daily backups, preferably from a cron job, and restore one of the backups to a secondary mongo database.

Our system is set up as follows:

- server 1: the development mongo database
- server 2: two mongo databases, one for staging data and one for production
- server 3: is where we run all of our cron jobs/batch scripts from.

I checked the mongo docs, and logged into our cron job server and tried to run the following command: (username, host, and password changed for security, I'm not actually connecting to localhost)

```
mongodump --host 127.0.0.1/development --port 27017 --username user --password pass --out /opt/backup/mongodump-2013-10-07-1
```

I get the following messages:

> Mon Oct  7 10:03:42 starting new replica set monitor for replica set 127.0.0.1 with seed of development:27017
>   Mon Oct  7 10:03:42 successfully connected to seed development:27017 for replica set 127.0.0.1
>   Mon Oct  7 10:03:42 warning: node: development:27017 isn't a part of set: 127.0.0.1 ismaster: { ismaster: true, maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216, ok: 1.0 }
>   Mon Oct  7 10:03:44 replica set monitor for replica set 127.0.0.1 started, address is 127.0.0.1/
>   Mon Oct  7 10:03:44 [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting couldn't connect to [127.0.0.1/development:27017] connect failed to set 127.0.0.1/development:27017

I confirmed that I can connect to the mongo database using `mongo -u -p ip/development`

Our ultimate goal will be to dump the data from the production database and store it in the staging database. These two databases are both located on the same box, if that makes a difference, but for testing purposes I am just trying to get a backup of development test data.

Comment: Try replacing `--host 127.0.0.1/development` with `--host 127.0.0.1 -d development`, it may solve your problem.

Comment: So it did, when I connect using `mongo -u -p` I just add the database after the host. Apparently that is not the appropriate way to handle it, at least for mongodump. The dump worked perfectly with that change

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`mongo` client can parse [MongoDB connection string URI](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/), so instead of specifying all connection parameters separately you may pass single connection string URI.

In your case you're trying to pass connection URI as a `host`, but `127.0.0.1/development` is not a valid host name. It means you should specify `database` parameter separately from the `host`:

```
mongodump --host 127.0.0.1 -d development --port 27017 --username user --password pass --out /opt/backup/mongodump-2013-10-07-1
```

Comment: `--authenticationDatabase admin` to authentiacte agains a specific table.

Comment: could you add arg structure for mongorestore command as well?

Comment: @sbk    mongorestore --host <ip> --port <port> --db <db_name> --authenticationDatabase <auth_db> --username <user-name> --password <pwd> collection <coll_name>  <db_backup_folder>

Answer (score 54):

You can use with mongodump with `--uri`

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb://usersname:password@127.0.0.1:27100/dbname?replicaSet=replica_name&authSource=admin" --out "C:\Umesh"
```

All your collections will store inside the out folder it will create directory name as your Database name and all the collections are bson and metadata will store as json format.

For restore

```
mongorestore --uri "mongodb://usersname:password@127.0.0.1:27100/dbname?replicaSet=replica_name&authSource=admin" -d dbname mongodbumppath
```

Try this it will work.

Answer (score 21):

> **This worked for me.**
>
> Reference: [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

**Syntax 1:**

```sh
mongodump --host <hostname:port> --db <database> --username <username> --password <password> --out <path>
```

**Syntax 2:**

```sh
mongodump -h <hostname:port> -d <database> -u <username> -p <password> -o <path>
```

---

**Example 1:**

```sh
mongodump --host 127.0.0.1:27017 --db db_app --username root --password secret --out /backup/db/app-17-03-07
```

**Example 2:**

```sh
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:27017 -d db_app -u root -p secret -o /backup/db/app-17-03-07
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mongodump --host remotehostip:port --db dbname -u username -p password
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of exporting collection from node server to local machine:

```
Host : xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
Port :27017
Username:”XXXX”
Password :”YYYY”
AuthDB : “admin”
“DB”: “mydb”

D:\mongodb-backup>mongodump -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx –port 27017 -u “XXXX” -p “YYYY” –authenticationDatabase “admin” –db “mydb”
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get dump using URI:

```
mongodump --uri=mongodb+srv://john:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@cluster0-jdtjt.mongodb.net/sales
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gzip for taking backup of one collection and compressing the backup on the fly

```
mongodump --db somedb --collection somecollection --out - | gzip > collectiondump.gz
```

Or with a date in the file name:

```
mongodump --db somedb --collection somecollection --out - | gzip > dump_`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked to me like a charm for a single collection with a remote Windows Server.

```
mongodump --host <remote_ip> --port <mongo_port> --db <remote_db_name>  --authenticationDatabase <remote_auth_db> --username <remote_mongo_username> --password <remote_db_pwd> --out <local_DB_backup_folder> --collection <remote_collection_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, this is what worked for me (but be sure to use your own real credentials):

```sh
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@5.0
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community

mongodump --uri "mongodb://usersname:password@127.0.0.1:27100/dbname" --out "/Users/some_username/code/mongodb_dumps/dump/"
cd /Users/some_username/code/mongodb_dumps/
mongorestore --nsInclude "*.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mongodump --host hostip -d dbname --port portnumber --username username --password password --authenticationDatabase admin -o ./path/of/backupfolder
```

note: "./path/of/backupfolder" path is in your client

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me:**

Step1: Export remote/local DB.

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD........." --out "/Users/Hardik/Desktop/mongo_bkp"
```

Step2: Import

```
mongorestore ./mongo_bkp/
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here in case it helps somebody.

It was impossible for me to connect using mongodump. I ended up installing the VS Code Mongo extension and it generated the string for me. The command looks like this:

```
mongodump -o dump_destination --uri "mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASENAME>?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary&ssl=true"
```