# copy collection from remote to local database

Tags: mongodb

mongo shell commands are needed to copy a collection from a database on a remote server to local database. 
Following the instructions as per the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/atlas-on-day-one-importing-data),
The commands to login to the remote database are:

```
mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017/admin?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --ssl --username <myName> --password
```

then type my password, then:

```
Cluster0-shard-0:PRIMARY> use myDatabase
switched to db myDatabase
Cluster0-shard-0:PRIMARY> mongodump -d myDatabase
2017-04-30T07:10:57.698+1000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:13
```

How can I move forward from here in order to get myCollection to my local database? thx

Answer (score 0):

You should run mongodump at the OS command line instead of the mongo shell, and specify your collection name as well as the database:

```
mongodump --db myDatabase --collection myCollection
```

mongodump will then create a dump folder, and a subfolder for the database containing the bson for the collection.  You can copy that over to where your local database resides.

You can then import it with mongorestore:

```
mongorestore -d myDatabase -c myCollection myCollection.bson
```

Comment: mongodump --db mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@cluster0-shard-00-00-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017/myDatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin --collection myCollection gives "-bash: !3: event not found"

Comment: The easiest thing would be to ssh to the remote server if you can.  If you can't, there's this post on how to specify the remote host for a mongodump: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228474/mongodump-from-remote-server.

You'll also need mongodump installed locally if you want to run it remotely.